# Is there a way to set the instruction text for HTML dropdown but not used as an option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I met a difficulty here in realizing a dropdown in JavaScript. Normally, we will achieve a default value of an HTML dropdown by setting:

```
 <option selected> blablabla </option>
```

However, now I am given a new request, which is used to make the dropdown show some helpful instruction text to the end user before she/he makes a choice. The drowdown options will be populated too. However, this piece of instruction text will NOT be used an option. So whenever the user collapses the dropdown, he/she will be not able to select this instruction text.

The code I wrote so far is:

```
for(var i=0;i<jsondata.length;i++){
        dropDown.append('<option  value="'+jsondata[i]   +'">'+jsondata[i]+'</option>');
    }
dropDown.append('<option selected>Please select a proper organization</option>');
```

However, this is not working well, since it will make the instruction text as a separate option.

I wonder if there is a way to achieve this in JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you please post some code, so we can try to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: @GibboK,updated with some code.

Comment: _“to make the dropdown show some helpful instruction text to the end user before she/he makes a choice”_ – instead of “hiding” that by using a fake option, you should consider using a `label`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with html only. Simply make the instructions options `disabled`

see this. http://jsfiddle.net/z8pfk2bg/

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo" disabled selected>please select a car</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Is also quite well supported in `>IE7`, and if you are populating the options using javascript http://jsfiddle.net/33dd3mfx/

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the `<option>` elements with an `<optgroup>`, the `label` of which sets the display text of the group of wrapped `<option>`s:

```js
var dropdown = $('#demo'),
  opts = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

for (var i = 0, len = opts.length; i < len; i++) {
  dropdown.append('<option value="' + opts[i] + '">' + opts[i] + '</option>');
}

dropdown.find('option').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Select a letter"></optgroup>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="demo"></select>
```

The down-side of this approach is that the 'label' text (your "Please select a proper organization") won't be visible until the user has focused the `<select>` element, unlike using a disabled `<option>`.

References:

- [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup).